# Reload Self Invoking Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatables

I have a little self invoking anonymous function I got on GitHub to make links Restful in Laravel, and added in a little Sweet Alerts sugar.

```
(function(window, $, undefined) {

    var Laravel = {
        initialize: function() {
            this.methodLinks = $('a[data-method]');
            this.token = $('a[data-token]');
            this.registerEvents();
        },

        registerEvents: function() {
            this.methodLinks.on('click', this.handleMethod);
        },

        handleMethod: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()

            var link = $(this)
            var httpMethod = link.data('method').toUpperCase()
            var form

            // If the data-method attribute is not PUT or DELETE,
            // or PATCH then we don't know what to do. Just ignore.
            if ($.inArray(httpMethod, ['PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH']) === -1) {
                return false
            }

            Laravel
                .verifyConfirm(link)
                .done(function () {
                    form = Laravel.createForm(link)
                    form.submit()
                })
        },

        verifyConfirm: function(link) {
            var confirm = new $.Deferred()

            swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: link.data('confirm'),
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
                closeOnConfirm: false
                },
                function(result) {
                    if (result) {
                        confirm.resolve(link);
                    } else {
                        confirm.reject(link);
                    }
                }
            );

            return confirm.promise()
        },

        createForm: function(link) {
            var form =
                $('<form>', {
                    'method': 'POST',
                    'action': link.attr('href')
                });

            var token =
                $('<input>', {
                    'type': 'hidden',
                    'name': '_token',
                    'value': link.data('token')
                });

            var hiddenInput =
                $('<input>', {
                    'name': '_method',
                    'type': 'hidden',
                    'value': link.data('method')
                });

            return form.append(token, hiddenInput)
                .appendTo('body');
        }
    };

    Laravel.initialize();

})(window, jQuery);
```

It works great when the tables are regular tables, but I have several `dataTables` tables that load some action links into a column in javascript.

When this happens I can't access this function since I assume it's out of scope, or it's already been loaded up.

I'm using the:

```
initComplete: function(settings, json) {
    //???? Laravel.initialize();
}
```

callback in the DataTable, but alas I still can't access anything.

Is there a way to export the object literal from the anonymous function so I can re-initialize it?

Or how else might I go about this?

Comment: `window.Laravel = {...` and you can invoke it like `window.Laravel.initialize();`

Comment: Brilliant man thanks. You should've submitted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of defining it as local variable, you could use it as `property` of `window` i.e. global variable.

> `window.Laravel = {...` and you can invoke it like `window.Laravel.initialize();` anywhere you want.